# How do I define host path rules with a GCP VPC VPN setup to a specific subnet with backend services running in a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: networking, vpn

We have a setup where we connect our Google Cloud project via VPN and VPC to a client. We have different dockerized spring boot services  ../session/.., ../execution/.. running in a Kubernetes cluster. How can we create a single endpoint in the VPC on a subnet 172.17.0.0/20 which the client can access via the VPN and call our services? I was thinking via the internal TCP load balancer of GCP, but there is no way to define the host rules to map /session/... to the session backend and so on. Should we do this then via port mapping? Because each of our services are running in different ports on the cluster.